# angular cli ng test : Can not load reporter "", it is not registered

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-cli, jasmine-reporters

I am trying the following command from https://cli.angular.io/reference.pdf

```
ng test --reporters
```

The following error is showing. Please tell me how to register reporter.

> ```
> 05 01 2017 12:47:19.437:ERROR [reporter]: Can not load reporter "", it is not re
> gistered!
>   Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
> 05 01 2017 12:47:44.876:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost
> :9876/
> 05 01 2017 12:47:44.894:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.2.0 server started at http://loca
> lhost:9876/
> 05 01 2017 12:47:44.895:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited
>  concurrency
> 05 01 2017 12:47:44.897:ERROR [karma]: Found 1 load error
> ```

Comment: where is the unit test reporter written?

Comment: I did not write any test reporter. The command is on the PDF file. I just run it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have able to figure out how to use reporters in angular-cli

I have updated the Karma configuration file (karma.conf.js) as follows

```
require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
```

and

```
reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul', 'kjhtml']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
```

Then run the following command to install the plugin

```
npm install karma-jasmine-html-reporter --save-dev
```

then I run

```
ng test --code-coverage
```

It is giving me a report like this [image: this]